# JAWS reading document title multiple times on Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jaws-screen-reader

JAWS is reading document title multiple times on Edge. On Chrome it's working fine.
I added react-helmet node package in my project and JAWS is reading the title multiple times on Edge.

eg.
My Title
My Title
My Title
My Title

```html
<Helmet>
  <title>My Title</title>
</Helmet>
```

Comment: Does it only happen with the react code?  Do you have a working example to test?  **When** is the title read multiple times?  When the page loads?  What happens if you use `Ins`+`T` to read the page title?

Comment: I am not sure its happened with react code or not. but this issue is only on IE. Right now I do not have working example. but I will create code.

Comment: Your question title says “Edge” but now you’re saying “IE”.  Which browser are you using?

Comment: Apologies for above. Issues on both but IE retires on 15 June. So just need fix for edge

Comment: Edge uses the same engine as Chrome so if you see the problem on Edge, try Chrome as well to see if it happens there.